# How to make Entry Boxes interact w/ each other in Python IDLE Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-idle

I am trying to make a basic area calculator that does this base*height=area

so far my code is this (at least the part you need to see)

```
#Labels and Boxes

def calculate():
    boxBase*boxHeight

buttonCalculate = Button(text = "Calculate area...", command = calculate)
buttonCalculate.grid(row =4, column =0)

myLabel3=Label(text="Area", fg="black")
myLabel3.grid(row =3, column =0, sticky='w')
boxSolution= Entry()
boxSolution.grid(row =3, column =1)

myLabel2=Label(text="Base", fg="black")
myLabel2.grid(row =0, column =0, sticky='w')
boxBase= Entry()
boxBase.grid(row =0, column =1)

myLabel=Label(text="Height", fg="black",)
myLabel.grid(row =1, column =0, sticky = "w")
boxHeight= Entry()
boxHeight.grid(row =1, column =1)
```

I want to make `boxBase` multiply by `boxHeight` and print to `boxSolution` when I press the `buttonCalculate` How can I do this?

Comment: `boxBase` and `boxHeight` are instances of widgets. Use the `.get()` method to return their values. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method

Comment: Hmmm whenever I try and .get() for example my boxBase it says "boxBase" is not defined? Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code and the full error and I'll tell you, otherwise it could be a number of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Python 2.7

```
#Labels and Boxes
from Tkinter import *

WD = Tk()
WD.geometry('350x250+50+200')
WD.title("Area")

solution = DoubleVar()
base = DoubleVar()
height = DoubleVar()
def calculate():
    boxSolution.delete(0,END)
    boxSolution.insert(0,(base.get())*(height.get()))

buttonCalculate = Button(WD,text = "Calculate area...", command = calculate)
buttonCalculate.grid(row =4, column =0)

myLabel3=Label(WD,text="Area", fg="black")
myLabel3.grid(row =3, column =0, sticky='w')
boxSolution= Entry(WD,textvariable=solution)
boxSolution.grid(row =3, column =1)

myLabel2=Label(WD,text="Base", fg="black")
myLabel2.grid(row =0, column =0, sticky='w')
boxBase= Entry(WD,textvariable=base)
boxBase.grid(row =0, column =1)

myLabel=Label(WD,text="Height", fg="black",)
myLabel.grid(row =1, column =0, sticky = "w")
boxHeight= Entry(WD,textvariable=height)
boxHeight.grid(row =1, column =1)

WD.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks I will, it seems like whenever I post something people always down vote it or try to close it? LOL thanks though man

Comment: Hehe, yea I see alot of that.. Anyways np man. Just ask me if u need help. I have made alot of calculation apps within python.

Comment: Hmmm I keep getting an error saying "Could not convert string to float"? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you input , instead of . maybe? :) like 1,5 should be 1.5

Comment: I edited the code. Changed StringVar() to DoubleVar(). And removed the float conversion. Then you dont have to think about that. But still it throws an error, if you input text.

Comment: Oooooh it worked thanks man! But for future references how could I get the number the user inputs into the box. I tried the .get() but it wouldn't work /: like I tried to do boxBase.get() and assign it as a variable called userBase but it gave me an error?

Comment: Use the textvariable.get().. in this case base.get() and height.get()

Comment: ok I tried doing this base = base.get()but it says the "base" from base.get() is not defined

Comment: You should not change base. base is now the textvariable inside boxBase= Entry(WD,textvariable=base).. You can use AnotherNewVariable = base.get()

Comment: I tried that as well by assigning it a new variable but it still said it wasnt defined

Comment: You must do that underneeth the other code. Can you email me the code.. or something bogisivertsen@gmail.com

Comment: sure I will email it and thanks for all the help btw